# Compact subset of a closed subspace: compact in the whole space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Imagine that you have a topological space $(X,\tau_{X})$ and a closed subset $Y$. Say that within $Y$ we have a subset $K$ that is compact in the subspace topology $\tau_Y$. Is $K$ compact  in $(X,\tau_{X})$?

Now similar results are known:

1) If $X$ is Hausdorff, the answer is yes.

2) If $Y$ is instead open, the answer is also yes.

Hope this is not a silly question!

Answer (score 4):

The topology induced on $K$ by $Y$ is the same as the topology induced by the topology on $X$ (since the topology on $Y$ is the one induced by the topology on $X$).

Now in general, a subset of a top. space is compact in that top. space iff it is compact in itself when given the subspace top.   Applying this to the above, we see
that K is compact in Y iff it is compact in X iff it is compact as a top. space in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $K\subseteq Y$ is compact. Let $\mathcal O$ be an open cover for $K$ in $X$. Then $K\subseteq \bigcup \mathcal O$ gives $K\cap Y=K\subseteq \bigcup \mathcal O\cap Y$. Thus $\mathcal O'=\mathcal O\cap Y$ is an open cover in $Y$ of $K$. Note I assumed *nothing* on $Y$ or $X$.

What you might be thinking about is that in Hausdorff spaces, compact sets are closed.

(I am denoting $\mathcal O\cap Y=\{O\cap Y:O\in \mathcal O\}$.)